# Explicitly returning from lambda expression in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, spark-java

Using [Spark](http://sparkjava.com/), I end up with a bit of code like this:

```
post("/auth/login", { req, res ->
    val body = parseBody(req.body())
    val assertion = body["assertion"]
    if (assertion == null) {
        halt(400)
        return null
    }
    // ...snip...lots more code
})
```

Which works great, except...it doesn't compile -- I get `'return' is not allowed here`.

I *could* put the remainder of the lambda in an `else` block, but I'd rather not in the interest of minimizing indentation.

So how do I "short circuit" the lambda to return a null?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In my understanding, Lambda cant use return, return is for the function by default.

So you need to use a label to tell the return clause where it will return to.
I use this:

```
f@ {
 ...
 return@f null
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. I had a sneaking suspicion the `return@` pattern would be involved...anyway, I found further docs here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/returns.html#return-at-labels (the second example in particular is relevant).

Answer (score 2):

I've found that this seems to work, though it's a little more verbose:

```
post("/auth/login", fun(req, res): Any? {
    val body = parseBody(req.body())
    val assertion = body["assertion"]
    if (assertion == null) {
        halt(400)
        return null
    }
    // ...snip...lots more code
    return null // or whatever
})
```

Comment: that's what i ended up using for Spark. Works great, the code overhead is tiny comparing to the size of the calls.